# javascript: getting the order of magnitude of a time interval

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, time, momentjs

I am writing an application which needs a bar plot, whose binning, in the *x* axis, is relative to the order of magnitude of the average time-distance between the events that are displayed.

For example, the average time distance in the events that I want to display might be 73 seconds. This means that the size of the bins relative to the bars that are displayed should be a minute.

Other examples of duration in seconds of the input interval and inferred order of magnitude are:

- 3 seconds: one second
- 327 seconds: one minute (or, possibly, 5 minutes)
- 5298 seconds: one hour
- 7625 seconds: (possibly) two hours
- 10234 seconds: one day
- 4023860 seconds: one month

and so on. I tried to look into the [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) library and I found out that they implemented something very interesting: the [`fromNow` method](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/).

Please note that I am also interested in the number of seconds of each order of magnitude that has been previously illustrated.

I know that I could implement it myself with a cascade of tests (divisions with rest), but I would like to reinvent the (possibly buggy) wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I implemented a solution in the following simple function:

```
function compute_magnitude_interval(average_interval) {
    var minute = 60;
    var hour = minute*60;
    var day = hour*24;

    var possible_intervals = [ 
        1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 30,
        minute, minute*2, minute*5, minute*10, minute*20, minute*30,
        hour, hour*2, hour*5, hour*10, hour*12,
        day, day*2, day*5, day*10, day*15
    ].reverse();

    for(var i in possible_intervals){
        var seconds = possible_intervals[i];
        if (Math.floor(average_interval/seconds) > 0) {
            return seconds;
        }
    };
}
```